# Does there exist a ranges::views::group_by counterpart that takes into account all elements, as opposed to just contiguous ones?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

In `C++20`'s `std::ranges`, we can expect getting [`views::group_by`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1views_1_1group__by__fn.html)<sup>1</sup>. This can be very handy, but I found a problem while playing with it. From Eric Niebler's [manual](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/?fbclid=IwAR0ZfqTLVIuRClA1SJrHv23ISmelcOsO86buEYm1vA-wGe5-yNkE8qA9opY) we can read that it "*In essence, `views::group_by` groups **contiguous** elements together with a binary predicate.*". Let's inspect an example. I have an `std::vector` of some `int`s and I want to *group* it into two ranges - representing even and odd numbers. My initial approach was to simply do:

```
int main() {
    using namespace ranges;

    std::vector<int> ints = {3, 9, 12, 10, 7, 5, 1, 4, 8};

    for (auto rng : ints | views::group_by(
            [](auto lhs, auto rhs) {
                const bool leftEven = lhs % 2 == 0;
                const bool rightEven = rhs % 2 == 0;

                return (leftEven && rightEven) || (!leftEven && !rightEven);
            })) {
        std::cout << rng << '\n';
    }
}
```

But that can't work. Or, to put it in another way, it will work, but yield unexpected (for some, I imagine) results for anyone familiar with similar operations in other languages (or even APIs). The output of this program is:

> ```
> [3,9]
> [12,10]
> [7,5,1]
> [4,8]
> ```

Even and odd numbers are not all grouped - that's because they are not all contiguous. `3` and `9` are paired together, becauase they are *both ood **and** contiguous*. Similarily (except from being *even*) `12` and `10`. But `7`, `5` and `1` will create a separate group - they won't be grouped with `3` and `9` and that's not what I would either want or expect.

What we could of course do is to `partition` the `ints` vector to order the elements so the evens and odds form two groups. The problem is... there is no **`views::`**`partition` in ranges. That leaves me with two options, where neither of them particularly appeals to me:

#### 1. <s>`std`</s>ranges::partition before viewing the vector:

Calling:

```
ranges::partition(ints, [](auto elem) { return elem % 2 == 0; });
```

just before our *range*-based `for` loop and we have our desired output:

> ```
> [8,4,12,10]
> [7,5,1,9,3]
> ```

I don't like it because it lacks composability - one of the `ranges`' key factor. I don't want to partition the vector either, to be honest. I want to print its elements in two groups - evens and odds.

#### 2. Use `actions::sort` and sort the vector using even-odd comparator:

```
int main() {
    using namespace ranges;

    std::vector<int> ints = {3, 9, 12, 10, 7, 5, 1, 4, 8};

    auto evens_first = [](auto lhs, auto rhs) { return lhs % 2 == 0 && rhs % 2 != 0; };

    for (auto rng : (ints |= actions::sort(evens_first)) | views::group_by(
            [](auto lhs, auto rhs) {
                const bool leftEven = lhs % 2 == 0;
                const bool rightEven = rhs % 2 == 0;

                return (leftEven && rightEven) || (!leftEven && !rightEven);
            })) {
        std::cout << rng << '\n';
    }
}
```

Note that the parenthesis around the `|=` operator are required, since otherwise the compose operator (`|`) of ranges will be evaluated first and we'll end up with the above code printing sorted elements of the vector, completely ignoring grouping (*???*).

This approach is *okaaaay*, but still not great. I'd much prefer to either have a `group_by` that could, for example, take a value and return a key (`Java`'s and `C#`'s approach of handling grouping) or anyhow take the whole range into account, or at least have `actions::partition` available.

Side note: I see the rationale behind `views::grouping_by` working just with contiguous elements. It's the most efficient way - no need to store anything, no need to go back or look further. It's okay and sometimes it's **the** best tool for the job. But I believe it creates confusion by being counterintuitive for people who have worked with similar APIs in the past.

And to finally repeat the question - is there any more concise way of doing what I want, based on the examples and desired approaches I proposed?

---

<sup>1</sup> I can't find it on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges), but I think I saw a confirmation somewhere that it's in. Correct me please if I am mistaken.

Comment: For reference, I don't see this particular view in the C++20 draft.

Comment: @chris same, hence the footnote

Comment: At this point, if it's not in the working draft, I expect it's not going to be in C++20. cppreference can lag behind depending mainly on how much time Tristan has, but the draft is getting more and more final each meeting.

Comment: Why not use `std::views::filter()`?

Comment: @deduplicator to do what, exactly?

Comment: To get the elements conforming to your predicate. And adding `std::not_fn()`, those who don't.

Comment: As an aside, why not `return !(lhs % 2) == !(rhs % 2);`?

Comment: @deduplicator I don't want to get the elements. I want to get two groups of elements in form of ranges. You could concatenate two filtered ranges, but that's *uhh*. As for the predicate - because `lhs % 2 == rhs % 2` is shorter ;>

Comment: Test it with elements `-1` and `+1`. Using my suggestion or your excessive one in the post, they are in the same group. But if you take them `% 2`, they are still `-1` and `+1`.

Comment: @deduplicator ah, just the predicate. Yup, you are right, your approach is better.

Comment: It's not in 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*group_by* in those other languages does not get a comparator for two elements, but a projection from the element to a tuple of relevant values, on which hashing and comparing works. Also, they are free to allocate additional memory to get the job done.

Here, *you don't pay for what you don't use* admittedly reduces your comfort slightly. You have to do that step explicitly if you need it, instead of the language forcing it on you even if it's just useless make-work.

Answer (score 1):

I currently have the same issue where i have a vector of objects. Each of them has a member which signifies which group i need them in.
The for now best solution i found is:

1. Sorting them by the member group id
2. Seperating / Chunking them using [ranges::view::chunk_by](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/chunk_by_view)
   The function provided to chunk_by would then simply check wether the two objects it receives have different group ids

Note that this solution works for any number of subgroups, not just two like in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

So you need a 'group by' operator in the SQL sense, right?
Just like sort action, a 'group by' operator in the SQL sense is an offline operator, it could not emit the first output element without seeing the last input element. Its offline nature makes it uncomposable intrincally.

Currently cpp ranges supports that behavior via a sort action and a group-by view, it is one method of implementing the 'group by' operation in SQL sense.

Certainly you could develop another implmentation via an custom action just like sort (but differently), and compose that with views::group_by.

Eg. std::partition is one method, or you could develop another better hash-based split method to group the input range into a range of buckets, the elements in each bucket share the same hash value (determined by a lambda passed into the split method).

Answer (score 0):

This is annoying. You really want some kind `filter` like view that takes invocable returning a enumeration and returns `std::array<std::vector<T>>`.

Or perhaps, have a you could `transform` to a variant, and have a `ranges::to_vector` like function that partitions a range of variants (i.e. returns `tuple<vector<Ts>...>`).